# Using JS window.print() breaks back button in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I let visitors click on an image to print the page

The site includes jQuery 1.6.3

In my script I've written the following:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#printButton').click(function(e) {
    print();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Where 'printButton' is appears in my html as

```
<img src="#" 
 id="printButton"
 ... />
```

The print dialog opens when the user clicks on the 'printButton.' So far so good.

But my back button no longer works in chrome. The browser doesn't go back to the
previous page until I close the print dialog. I just get the little grey spinner on the tab.

This doesn't happen if I just click CTRL-P. I can go back to the previous page even when
the print dialog is still open.

I've tried this on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107

Any ideas on how to fix my back button?

Comment: you have a TYPO on your line:4 it should be `});` not `)};` same goes for the last line.

Comment: **In Chrome 32.0.1700.107m it works**

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you had one tab with NO history = no back button. But I guess you didnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Congratulations, it appears like you've found a bug in Google Chrome. In that case there isn't much you can do about it, other than report or forget it.